# Does JQuery have any execution speed disadvantages that could be noticeable in a very large scale web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

When choosing between JQuery and raw JS in a very large scale web application, it's very clear that JQuery will promise a much faster development phase, on many levels, and allow code to be more manageable afterwards.

**But what I'm wondering is if, on a highly complex web application with very active dynamic content, might it be better to use raw Javascript? Does JQuery have any performance effect that might be noticed in a large application?**

**Note:**
*It seems to me that with JQuery, you've got to be sacrificing some execution efficiency with the sort of filtering that JQuery is applying to the script. If everything must run through JQuery rather than being processed directly, it seemly like there should be some performance efficiency decrease.*

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *is* processed directly. It is a series of utility functions, written in Javascript. I think you're imagining it as some kind of abstraction layer that must be parsed and/or lexed independently: it's not.

So you are apparently succumbing to random [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt), but if this is a concern for you then you ought to simply benchmark both options and find out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I see. What I guess I was imagining wasn't that JQuery was parsed separately, but that more needed to be parsed, using it.

Comment: @jt0dd: Indeed, but that's not true. They're just Javascript functions. The `$` may throw you off but it's just a valid character in a Javascript function name; that's it! The only way you may fall over here is if any given jQuery function happens to do a little more than you really need for your precise application: this ought to be incredibly rare, but if you have _intense_ performance requirements you may wish to write tighter code. That's where the benchmarking comes in and, frankly, I'd still be surprised to see jQuery lose out there: its facilities are generally quite atomic.

Answer (score 0):

No. jQuery, used correctly, has no significant negative performance impact on your site/application.

Answer (score 0):

All technologies perform poorly when used poorly. JQuery is no exception.

But if you use JQuery in an optimal way, you will be fine. There are numerous resources on the web for using JQuery properly. [Here](http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2013/10/10/tips-optimize-jQuery-Code) is a recent one.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful page.

Comment: No problem. Those are pretty simple tips too. Keep in mind that JQuery is extremely popular and has been around so long for a reason. If there were prohibitive performance concerns, they would've been at least known if not addressed by now.

Comment: ... unless they were systemic and/or fundamental.

Comment: Like I said...at least known.